# No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package while running on Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch some data from snowflake. The script is running absolutely fine while running on local but when I am trying to run it on Jenkins while creating a freestyle project , its giving the following error -
import snowflake.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package.

pip install snowflake-connector-python command is already included in the cmd of jenkins.

Looking for a solution on prioriy basis.

Answer (score 0):

To check the Python environment that Jenkins is using, you can add the following command to your Jenkins build script:

```
which python
```

This command will print the path of the Python interpreter that Jenkins is using. You can compare this path to the one on your local machine to make sure that Jenkins is using the same Python environment.

If Jenkins is using a different Python environment, you can install snowflake-connector-python in that environment by adding the following command to your Jenkins build script:

```
/path/to/python -m pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

Replace /path/to/python with the path to the Python interpreter that Jenkins is using.